# Responsive design not zooming out from mobile [@media queries]

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm new to this and not really understand why is this happening and how to solve this.

I'm building my web-site with @media queries to be mobile-friendly. When I'm accessing the site from mobile I see the mobile-friendly version as I should, but when I'm trying to switch for desktop-view, the mobile-friendly version is remained and the desktop(normal) isn't showing.

With my *.css file I did as following:

```
my styles for global(normal - desktop) view
...
...
...
@media (max-width:500px){
my styles for mobile-friendly view
}
```

I don't want to use `@media` for my desktop view as not all browsers support `@media`, just in case some one will think it may solve this problem.

Hope for your help

Comment: Hmm it seems alright. Do you have any live version?

Comment: No, it's not on the web yet. I used Android WebView 4(default browser) as it most common. But with latest chrome version for Android its the same. Firefox display the desktop version as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Always ensure you include the following `<meta>` tag within your `<head> </head>` element:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

The *viewport* tag is used to serve your website in a certain style regardless of device. The `width` property controls the size of the viewport *(the virtual "window")* and can be set to a specific pixel size, or the width of the device. The `initial-scale` property controls the zoom level when the page is loaded. `maximum-scale`, `minimum-scale`, and `user-scalable` all control how users are allowed to zoom the page in out out.

I personally have disabled user-scalable to keep a consistent page view, like when a user focuses on a select element it ensures the page does not zoom. Let me know if this fixes your problem, otherwise I will need some example of your CSS to figure out your problem! Cheers ~

Comment: No, unfortunately this isn't solve the problem. I think I need to add something beyond the normal coding in my *.css file, as this problem present on many other sites. Just in order to test it, I went here: http://mediaqueri.es/ and test a few web-sites and the behavior are the exact the same as with my web-site.

Answer (score 0):

The only browsers that do not support media queries are IE 5 to 8.  IE 9+ supports it.  Less than 1% of my website views come from an Internet Explorer browser, so in my opinion I would not sacrifice a good design for IE.  I would recommend to always code mobile first, and after implement size specifications.

Implementing the viewport in the head section of your page **is a must**.
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

I wouldn't use a `max-width:500px` since this is a random max width...  Stick to the correct ones, and your CSS will look like this:

```
*-- SINCE WE ARE CODING MOBILE-FIRST, WE DO NOT NEED A MEDIA QUERY FOR IT --*/

Enter all base code here

/*-- TABLET --*/
@media(min-width: 641px) {
    ...
} 
/*-- SMALL DESKTOP --*/
@media(min-width: 768px) {
    ...
} 
/*-- DESKTOP --*/
@media(min-width: 992px) {
    ...
} 
/*-- BIG DESKTOP (rarely used, but can be useful) --*/
@media(min-width: 1280px) {
    ...
}
```

Coding mobile-first CSS will simplify your code and create a solid style base. Switching your habits to mobile-first coding will be a plus for you and the designers that may eventually need to work with your layouts. This should be considered an effective method to help create bulletproof responsive designs.